# Cannot manage to send String DateType to OPC UA from Http Request

Tags: httprequest, node-red, opc-ua, node-opcua

#### Which node-red-contrib-iiot-opcua version are you using?

4.0.9

#### What happened?

I'm trying to send an HTTP request over OPC UA node, but it's not working at all. The string node never updates.

#### Server

OPCUA-IIoT-Flex-Server Node (Please attach AddressSpaceScript to the next section)

#### How can this be reproduced?

Export.json:

```
    {
        "id": "e92d7a441a9d8f99",
        "type": "tab",
        "label": "Flow 1",
        "disabled": false,
        "info": "",
        "env": []
    },
    {
        "id": "d82207d63fdea7e6",
        "type": "inject",
        "z": "e92d7a441a9d8f99",
        "name": "CicloRepetición",
        "props": [
            {
                "p": "payload"
            },
            {
                "p": "topic",
                "vt": "str"
            }
        ],
        "repeat": "5",
        "crontab": "",
        "once": true,
        "onceDelay": "0.5",
        "topic": "",
        "payload": "",
        "payloadType": "date",
        "x": 150,
        "y": 180,
        "wires": [
            [
                "873a84fa008fe370"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "9e551e92d50d566d",
        "type": "OPCUA-IIoT-Flex-Server",
        "z": "e92d7a441a9d8f99",
        "port": "55480",
        "endpoint": "",
        "acceptExternalCommands": true,
        "maxAllowedSessionNumber": "",
        "maxConnectionsPerEndpoint": "",
        "maxAllowedSubscriptionNumber": "",
        "alternateHostname": "",
        "name": "Servidor OPC UA",
        "showStatusActivities": true,
        "showErrors": true,
        "allowAnonymous": true,
        "individualCerts": false,
        "isAuditing": false,
        "serverDiscovery": true,
        "users": [],
        "xmlsets": [],
        "publicCertificateFile": "",
        "privateCertificateFile": "",
        "registerServerMethod": "1",
        "discoveryServerEndpointUrl": "",
        "capabilitiesForMDNS": "",
        "maxNodesPerRead": 1000,
        "maxNodesPerBrowse": 2000,
        "delayToClose": 1000,
        "addressSpaceScript": "/**\n* @param {any} server\n* @param {{ getOwnNamespace: () => any; findNode: (arg0: string) => any; }} addressSpace\n* @param {any} eventObjects\n* @param {() => void} done\n*/\nfunction constructAlarmAddressSpace(server, addressSpace, eventObjects, done) {\n    // server = the created node-opcua server\n    // addressSpace = script placeholder\n    // eventObjects = to hold event variables in memory from this script\n    \n    // internal global sandbox objects are \n    // node = node of the flex server, \n    // coreServer = core iiot server object for debug and access to nodeOPCUA,\n    // and scriptObjects to hold variables and functions\n    const LocalizedText = opcua.LocalizedText;\n    const namespace = addressSpace.getOwnNamespace();\n    \n    coreServer.internalDebugLog('init dynamic address space')\n    node.warn('construct new address space for OPC UA')\n    \n    const Variant = opcua.Variant;\n    const DataType = opcua.DataType;\n    const DataValue = opcua.DataValue;\n\n    // node.log(JSON.stringify(eventObjects));\n    // node.log(JSON.stringify(server));\n    \n    var $this = this;\n\n    this.sandboxFlowContext.set(\"ApiFact\", \"\");\n\n    node.log($this.sandboxFlowContext.get(\"ApiFact\"));\n    \n    coreServer.internalDebugLog(\"init dynamic address space\");\n    const rootFolder = addressSpace.findNode(\"RootFolder\");\n    \n    node.warn(\"construct new address space for OPC UA\");\n    \n    const myDevice = namespace.addFolder(rootFolder.objects, {\n    \"browseName\": \"FotovoltaicasDallas\"\n    });\n\n    const apiFact = namespace.addVariable({\n    \"organizedBy\": myDevice,\n    \"browseName\": \"ApiFact\",\n    \"nodeId\": \"ns=1;s=ApiFact\",\n    \"dataType\": \"String\",\n    \"value\": {\n      \"get\": function() {\n        return new Variant({\n          \"dataType\": DataType.String,\n          \"value\": $this.sandboxFlowContext.get(\"ApiFact\")\n        });\n      }\n      /*,\n      \"set\": function(variant) {\n        flexServerInternals.sandboxFlowContext.set(\n          \"apiFact\",\n          parseFloat(variant.value) // TODO\n        );\n        return opcua.StatusCodes.Good;\n      }\n      */\n    }\n    });\n    \n    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n    // Add a view\n    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n    const viewDI = namespace.addView({\n    \"organizedBy\": rootFolder.views,\n    \"browseName\": \"FotovoltaicasDallas-View\"\n    });\n    \n    viewDI.addReference({\n    \"referenceType\": \"Organizes\",\n    \"nodeId\": apiFact.nodeId\n    });\n    \n    coreServer.internalDebugLog(\"create dynamic address space done\");\n    node.warn(\"construction of new address space for OPC UA done\");\n    \n    done();\n}\n",
        "x": 690,
        "y": 200,
        "wires": [
            []
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "1c27f9ba47285ad5",
        "type": "function",
        "z": "e92d7a441a9d8f99",
        "name": "Asignar Flow",
        "func": "// El input de este nodo se lee por \"msg.payload\"\n// Aquí se recibirá el objeto que la api devuelva por su output.\n\n// node.log(JSON.stringify(msg.payload, null, 2));\n\nflow.set('ApiFact', msg.payload.fact);\nflow.set('ApiLength', msg.payload.length);\n\nmsg.test = {\n    ApiFact: msg.payload.fact\n}\n\nreturn msg;",
        "outputs": 1,
        "noerr": 0,
        "initialize": "",
        "finalize": "",
        "libs": [],
        "x": 410,
        "y": 200,
        "wires": [
            []
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "873a84fa008fe370",
        "type": "http request",
        "z": "e92d7a441a9d8f99",
        "name": "FotovoltaicaDallas API Request",
        "method": "GET",
        "ret": "txt",
        "paytoqs": "ignore",
        "url": "https://catfact.ninja/fact",
        "tls": "",
        "persist": false,
        "proxy": "",
        "insecureHTTPParser": false,
        "authType": "",
        "senderr": false,
        "headers": [],
        "x": 370,
        "y": 80,
        "wires": [
            [
                "eb69022b3c8d6327",
                "1c27f9ba47285ad5"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "eb69022b3c8d6327",
        "type": "debug",
        "z": "e92d7a441a9d8f99",
        "name": "debug 1",
        "active": true,
        "tosidebar": true,
        "console": false,
        "tostatus": true,
        "complete": "payload",
        "targetType": "msg",
        "statusVal": "payload",
        "statusType": "auto",
        "x": 620,
        "y": 80,
        "wires": []
    },
    {
        "id": "4383d0f36f9b9625",
        "type": "opcua-compact-server",
        "z": "e92d7a441a9d8f99",
        "d": true,
        "port": 54846,
        "endpoint": "",
        "productUri": "",
        "acceptExternalCommands": true,
        "maxAllowedSessionNumber": "10",
        "maxConnectionsPerEndpoint": "10",
        "maxAllowedSubscriptionNumber": "100",
        "alternateHostname": "",
        "name": "",
        "showStatusActivities": false,
        "showErrors": true,
        "allowAnonymous": true,
        "individualCerts": false,
        "isAuditing": false,
        "serverDiscovery": true,
        "users": [],
        "xmlsetsOPCUA": [],
        "publicCertificateFile": "",
        "privateCertificateFile": "",
        "registerServerMethod": "1",
        "discoveryServerEndpointUrl": "",
        "capabilitiesForMDNS": "",
        "maxNodesPerRead": 1000,
        "maxNodesPerWrite": 1000,
        "maxNodesPerHistoryReadData": 100,
        "maxNodesPerBrowse": 3000,
        "maxBrowseContinuationPoints": "10",
        "maxHistoryContinuationPoints": "10",
        "delayToInit": "1000",
        "delayToClose": "200",
        "serverShutdownTimeout": "100",
        "addressSpaceScript": "function constructAlarmAddressSpace(server, addressSpace, eventObjects, done) {\n  // server = the created node-opcua server\n  // addressSpace = address space of the node-opcua server\n  // eventObjects = add event variables here to hold them in memory from this script\n\n  // internal sandbox objects are:\n  // node = the compact server node,\n  // coreServer = core compact server object for debug and access to NodeOPCUA\n  // this.sandboxNodeContext = node context node-red\n  // this.sandboxFlowContext = flow context node-red\n  // this.sandboxGlobalContext = global context node-red\n  // this.sandboxEnv = env variables\n  // timeout and interval functions as expected from nodejs\n\n  const opcua = coreServer.choreCompact.opcua;\n  const LocalizedText = opcua.LocalizedText;\n  const namespace = addressSpace.getOwnNamespace();\n\n  const Variant = opcua.Variant;\n  const DataType = opcua.DataType;\n  const DataValue = opcua.DataValue;\n\n  var flexServerInternals = this;\n\n  this.sandboxFlowContext.set(\"isoInput1\", 0);\n  this.setInterval(() => {\n    flexServerInternals.sandboxFlowContext.set(\n      \"isoInput1\",\n      Math.random() + 50.0\n    );\n  }, 500);\n  this.sandboxFlowContext.set(\"isoInput2\", 0);\n  this.sandboxFlowContext.set(\"isoInput3\", 0);\n  this.sandboxFlowContext.set(\"isoInput4\", 0);\n  this.sandboxFlowContext.set(\"isoInput5\", 0);\n  this.sandboxFlowContext.set(\"isoInput6\", 0);\n  this.sandboxFlowContext.set(\"isoInput7\", 0);\n  this.sandboxFlowContext.set(\"isoInput8\", 0);\n\n  this.sandboxFlowContext.set(\"isoOutput1\", 0);\n  this.setInterval(() => {\n    flexServerInternals.sandboxFlowContext.set(\n      \"isoOutput1\",\n      Math.random() + 10.0\n    );\n  }, 500);\n\n  this.sandboxFlowContext.set(\"isoOutput2\", 0);\n  this.sandboxFlowContext.set(\"isoOutput3\", 0);\n  this.sandboxFlowContext.set(\"isoOutput4\", 0);\n  this.sandboxFlowContext.set(\"isoOutput5\", 0);\n  this.sandboxFlowContext.set(\"isoOutput6\", 0);\n  this.sandboxFlowContext.set(\"isoOutput7\", 0);\n  this.sandboxFlowContext.set(\"isoOutput8\", 0);\n\n  coreServer.debugLog(\"init dynamic address space\");\n  const rootFolder = addressSpace.findNode(\"RootFolder\");\n\n  node.warn(\"construct new address space for OPC UA\");\n\n  const myDevice = namespace.addFolder(rootFolder.objects, {\n    \"browseName\": \"RaspberryPI-Zero-WLAN\"\n  });\n  const gpioFolder = namespace.addFolder(myDevice, { \"browseName\": \"GPIO\" });\n  const isoInputs = namespace.addFolder(gpioFolder, {\n    \"browseName\": \"Inputs\"\n  });\n  const isoOutputs = namespace.addFolder(gpioFolder, {\n    \"browseName\": \"Outputs\"\n  });\n\n  const gpioDI1 = namespace.addVariable({\n    \"organizedBy\": isoInputs,\n    \"browseName\": \"I1\",\n    \"nodeId\": \"ns=1;s=Isolated_Input1\",\n    \"dataType\": \"Double\",\n    \"value\": {\n      \"get\": function() {\n        return new Variant({\n          \"dataType\": DataType.Double,\n          \"value\": flexServerInternals.sandboxFlowContext.get(\"isoInput1\")\n        });\n      },\n      \"set\": function(variant) {\n        flexServerInternals.sandboxFlowContext.set(\n          \"isoInput1\",\n          parseFloat(variant.value)\n        );\n        return opcua.StatusCodes.Good;\n      }\n    }\n  });\n\n  const gpioDI2 = namespace.addVariable({\n    \"organizedBy\": isoInputs,\n    \"browseName\": \"I2\",\n    \"nodeId\": \"ns=1;s=Isolated_Input2\",\n    \"dataType\": \"Double\",\n    \"value\": {\n      \"get\": function() {\n        return new Variant({\n          \"dataType\": DataType.Double,\n          \"value\": flexServerInternals.sandboxFlowContext.get(\"isoInput2\")\n        });\n      },\n      \"set\": function(variant) {\n        flexServerInternals.sandboxFlowContext.set(\n          \"isoInput2\",\n          parseFloat(variant.value)\n        );\n        return opcua.StatusCodes.Good;\n      }\n    }\n  });\n\n  const gpioDI3 = namespace.addVariable({\n    \"organizedBy\": isoInputs,\n    \"browseName\": \"I3\",\n    \"nodeId\": \"ns=1;s=Isolated_Input3\",\n    \"dataType\": \"Double\",\n    \"value\": {\n      \"get\": function() {\n        return new Variant({\n          \"dataType\": DataType.Double,\n          \"value\": flexServerInternals.sandboxFlowContext.get(\"isoInput3\")\n        });\n      },\n      \"set\": function(variant) {\n        flexServerInternals.sandboxFlowContext.set(\n          \"isoInput3\",\n          parseFloat(variant.value)\n        );\n        return opcua.StatusCodes.Good;\n      }\n    }\n  });\n\n  const gpioDI4 = namespace.addVariable({\n    \"organizedBy\": isoInputs,\n    \"browseName\": \"I4\",\n    \"nodeId\": \"ns=1;s=Isolated_Input4\",\n    \"dataType\": \"Double\",\n    \"value\": {\n      \"get\": function() {\n        return new Variant({\n          \"dataType\": DataType.Double,\n          \"value\": flexServerInternals.sandboxFlowContext.get(\"isoInput4\")\n        });\n      },\n      \"set\": function(variant) {\n        flexServerInternals.sandboxFlowContext.set(\n          \"isoInput4\",\n          parseFloat(variant.value)\n        );\n        return opcua.StatusCodes.Good;\n      }\n    }\n  });\n\n  const gpioDI5 = namespace.addVariable({\n    \"organizedBy\": isoInputs,\n    \"browseName\": \"I5\",\n    \"nodeId\": \"ns=1;s=Isolated_Input5\",\n    \"dataType\": \"Double\",\n    \"value\": {\n      \"get\": function() {\n        return new Variant({\n          \"dataType\": DataType.Double,\n          \"value\": flexServerInternals.sandboxFlowContext.get(\"isoInput5\")\n        });\n      },\n      \"set\": function(variant) {\n        flexServerInternals.sandboxFlowContext.set(\n          \"isoInput5\",\n          parseFloat(variant.value)\n        );\n        return opcua.StatusCodes.Good;\n      }\n    }\n  });\n\n  const gpioDI6 = namespace.addVariable({\n    \"organizedBy\": isoInputs,\n    \"browseName\": \"I6\",\n    \"nodeId\": \"ns=1;s=Isolated_Input6\",\n    \"dataType\": \"Double\",\n    \"value\": {\n      \"get\": function() {\n        return new Variant({\n          \"dataType\": DataType.Double,\n          \"value\": flexServerInternals.sandboxFlowContext.get(\"isoInput6\")\n        });\n      },\n      \"set\": function(variant) {\n        flexServerInternals.sandboxFlowContext.set(\n          \"isoInput6\",\n          parseFloat(variant.value)\n        );\n        return opcua.StatusCodes.Good;\n      }\n    }\n  });\n\n  const gpioDI7 = namespace.addVariable({\n    \"organizedBy\": isoInputs,\n    \"browseName\": \"I7\",\n    \"nodeId\": \"ns=1;s=Isolated_Input7\",\n    \"dataType\": \"Double\",\n    \"value\": {\n      \"get\": function() {\n        return new Variant({\n          \"dataType\": DataType.Double,\n          \"value\": flexServerInternals.sandboxFlowContext.get(\"isoInput7\")\n        });\n      },\n      \"set\": function(variant) {\n        flexServerInternals.sandboxFlowContext.set(\n          \"isoInput7\",\n          parseFloat(variant.value)\n        );\n        return opcua.StatusCodes.Good;\n      }\n    }\n  });\n\n  const gpioDI8 = namespace.addVariable({\n    \"organizedBy\": isoInputs,\n    \"browseName\": \"I8\",\n    \"nodeId\": \"ns=1;s=Isolated_Input8\",\n    \"dataType\": \"Double\",\n    \"value\": {\n      \"get\": function() {\n        return new Variant({\n          \"dataType\": DataType.Double,\n          \"value\": flexServerInternals.sandboxFlowContext.get(\"isoInput8\")\n        });\n      },\n      \"set\": function(variant) {\n        flexServerInternals.sandboxFlowContext.set(\n          \"isoInput8\",\n          parseFloat(variant.value)\n        );\n        return opcua.StatusCodes.Good;\n      }\n    }\n  });\n\n  const gpioDO1 = namespace.addVariable({\n    \"organizedBy\": isoOutputs,\n    \"browseName\": \"O1\",\n    \"nodeId\": \"ns=1;s=Isolated_Output1\",\n    \"dataType\": \"Double\",\n    \"value\": {\n      \"get\": function() {\n        return new Variant({\n          \"dataType\": DataType.Double,\n          \"value\": flexServerInternals.sandboxFlowContext.get(\"isoOutput1\")\n        });\n      },\n      \"set\": function(variant) {\n        flexServerInternals.sandboxFlowContext.set(\n          \"isoOutput1\",\n          parseFloat(variant.value)\n        );\n        return opcua.StatusCodes.Good;\n      }\n    }\n  });\n\n  const gpioDO2 = namespace.addVariable({\n    \"organizedBy\": isoOutputs,\n    \"browseName\": \"O2\",\n    \"nodeId\": \"ns=1;s=Isolated_Output2\",\n    \"dataType\": \"Double\",\n    \"value\": {\n      \"get\": function() {\n        return new Variant({\n          \"dataType\": DataType.Double,\n          \"value\": flexServerInternals.sandboxFlowContext.get(\"isoOutput2\")\n        });\n      },\n      \"set\": function(variant) {\n        flexServerInternals.sandboxFlowContext.set(\n          \"isoOutput2\",\n          parseFloat(variant.value)\n        );\n        return opcua.StatusCodes.Good;\n      }\n    }\n  });\n\n  const gpioDO3 = namespace.addVariable({\n    \"organizedBy\": isoOutputs,\n    \"browseName\": \"O3\",\n    \"nodeId\": \"ns=1;s=Isolated_Output3\",\n    \"dataType\": \"Double\",\n    \"value\": {\n      \"get\": function() {\n        return new Variant({\n          \"dataType\": DataType.Double,\n          \"value\": flexServerInternals.sandboxFlowContext.get(\"isoOutput3\")\n        });\n      },\n      \"set\": function(variant) {\n        flexServerInternals.sandboxFlowContext.set(\n          \"isoOutput3\",\n          parseFloat(variant.value)\n        );\n        return opcua.StatusCodes.Good;\n      }\n    }\n  });\n\n  const gpioDO4 = namespace.addVariable({\n    \"organizedBy\": isoOutputs,\n    \"browseName\": \"O4\",\n    \"nodeId\": \"ns=1;s=Isolated_Output4\",\n    \"dataType\": \"Double\",\n    \"value\": {\n      \"get\": function() {\n        return new Variant({\n          \"dataType\": DataType.Double,\n          \"value\": flexServerInternals.sandboxFlowContext.get(\"isoOutput4\")\n        });\n      },\n      \"set\": function(variant) {\n        flexServerInternals.sandboxFlowContext.set(\n          \"isoOutput4\",\n          parseFloat(variant.value)\n        );\n        return opcua.StatusCodes.Good;\n      }\n    }\n  });\n\n  const gpioDO5 = namespace.addVariable({\n    \"organizedBy\": isoOutputs,\n    \"browseName\": \"O5\",\n    \"nodeId\": \"ns=1;s=Isolated_Output5\",\n    \"dataType\": \"Double\",\n    \"value\": {\n      \"get\": function() {\n        return new Variant({\n          \"dataType\": DataType.Double,\n          \"value\": flexServerInternals.sandboxFlowContext.get(\"isoOutput5\")\n        });\n      },\n      \"set\": function(variant) {\n        flexServerInternals.sandboxFlowContext.set(\n          \"isoOutput5\",\n          parseFloat(variant.value)\n        );\n        return opcua.StatusCodes.Good;\n      }\n    }\n  });\n\n  const gpioDO6 = namespace.addVariable({\n    \"organizedBy\": isoOutputs,\n    \"browseName\": \"O6\",\n    \"nodeId\": \"ns=1;s=Isolated_Output6\",\n    \"dataType\": \"Double\",\n    \"value\": {\n      \"get\": function() {\n        return new Variant({\n          \"dataType\": DataType.Double,\n          \"value\": flexServerInternals.sandboxFlowContext.get(\"isoOutput6\")\n        });\n      },\n      \"set\": function(variant) {\n        flexServerInternals.sandboxFlowContext.set(\n          \"isoOutput6\",\n          parseFloat(variant.value)\n        );\n        return opcua.StatusCodes.Good;\n      }\n    }\n  });\n\n  const gpioDO7 = namespace.addVariable({\n    \"organizedBy\": isoOutputs,\n    \"browseName\": \"O7\",\n    \"nodeId\": \"ns=1;s=Isolated_Output7\",\n    \"dataType\": \"Double\",\n    \"value\": {\n      \"get\": function() {\n        return new Variant({\n          \"dataType\": DataType.Double,\n          \"value\": flexServerInternals.sandboxFlowContext.get(\"isoOutput7\")\n        });\n      },\n      \"set\": function(variant) {\n        flexServerInternals.sandboxFlowContext.set(\n          \"isoOutput7\",\n          parseFloat(variant.value)\n        );\n        return opcua.StatusCodes.Good;\n      }\n    }\n  });\n\n  const gpioDO8 = namespace.addVariable({\n    \"organizedBy\": isoOutputs,\n    \"browseName\": \"O8\",\n    \"nodeId\": \"ns=1;s=Isolated_Output8\",\n    \"dataType\": \"Double\",\n    \"value\": {\n      \"get\": function() {\n        return new Variant({\n          \"dataType\": DataType.Double,\n          \"value\": flexServerInternals.sandboxFlowContext.get(\"isoOutput8\")\n        });\n      },\n      \"set\": function(variant) {\n        flexServerInternals.sandboxFlowContext.set(\n          \"isoOutput8\",\n          parseFloat(variant.value)\n        );\n        return opcua.StatusCodes.Good;\n      }\n    }\n  });\n\n  //------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n  // Add a view\n  //------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n  const viewDI = namespace.addView({\n    \"organizedBy\": rootFolder.views,\n    \"browseName\": \"RPIW0-Digital-Ins\"\n  });\n\n  const viewDO = namespace.addView({\n    \"organizedBy\": rootFolder.views,\n    \"browseName\": \"RPIW0-Digital-Outs\"\n  });\n\n  viewDI.addReference({\n    \"referenceType\": \"Organizes\",\n    \"nodeId\": gpioDI1.nodeId\n  });\n\n  viewDI.addReference({\n    \"referenceType\": \"Organizes\",\n    \"nodeId\": gpioDI2.nodeId\n  });\n\n  viewDI.addReference({\n    \"referenceType\": \"Organizes\",\n    \"nodeId\": gpioDI3.nodeId\n  });\n\n  viewDI.addReference({\n    \"referenceType\": \"Organizes\",\n    \"nodeId\": gpioDI4.nodeId\n  });\n\n  viewDI.addReference({\n    \"referenceType\": \"Organizes\",\n    \"nodeId\": gpioDI5.nodeId\n  });\n\n  viewDI.addReference({\n    \"referenceType\": \"Organizes\",\n    \"nodeId\": gpioDI6.nodeId\n  });\n\n  viewDI.addReference({\n    \"referenceType\": \"Organizes\",\n    \"nodeId\": gpioDI7.nodeId\n  });\n\n  viewDI.addReference({\n    \"referenceType\": \"Organizes\",\n    \"nodeId\": gpioDI8.nodeId\n  });\n\n  viewDO.addReference({\n    \"referenceType\": \"Organizes\",\n    \"nodeId\": gpioDO1.nodeId\n  });\n\n  viewDO.addReference({\n    \"referenceType\": \"Organizes\",\n    \"nodeId\": gpioDO2.nodeId\n  });\n\n  viewDO.addReference({\n    \"referenceType\": \"Organizes\",\n    \"nodeId\": gpioDO3.nodeId\n  });\n\n  viewDO.addReference({\n    \"referenceType\": \"Organizes\",\n    \"nodeId\": gpioDO4.nodeId\n  });\n\n  viewDO.addReference({\n    \"referenceType\": \"Organizes\",\n    \"nodeId\": gpioDO5.nodeId\n  });\n\n  viewDO.addReference({\n    \"referenceType\": \"Organizes\",\n    \"nodeId\": gpioDO6.nodeId\n  });\n\n  viewDO.addReference({\n    \"referenceType\": \"Organizes\",\n    \"nodeId\": gpioDO7.nodeId\n  });\n\n  viewDO.addReference({\n    \"referenceType\": \"Organizes\",\n    \"nodeId\": gpioDO8.nodeId\n  });\n\n  coreServer.debugLog(\"create dynamic address space done\");\n  node.warn(\"construction of new address space for OPC UA done\");\n\n  done();\n}\n",
        "x": 680,
        "y": 280,
        "wires": []
    }
]
```

**AdressSpace:**

```
/**
* @param {any} server
* @param {{ getOwnNamespace: () => any; findNode: (arg0: string) => any; }} addressSpace
* @param {any} eventObjects
* @param {() => void} done
*/
function constructAlarmAddressSpace(server, addressSpace, eventObjects, done) {
    // server = the created node-opcua server
    // addressSpace = script placeholder
    // eventObjects = to hold event variables in memory from this script
    
    // internal global sandbox objects are 
    // node = node of the flex server, 
    // coreServer = core iiot server object for debug and access to nodeOPCUA,
    // and scriptObjects to hold variables and functions
    const LocalizedText = opcua.LocalizedText;
    const namespace = addressSpace.getOwnNamespace();
    
    coreServer.internalDebugLog('init dynamic address space')
    node.warn('construct new address space for OPC UA')
    
    const Variant = opcua.Variant;
    const DataType = opcua.DataType;
    const DataValue = opcua.DataValue;

    // node.log(JSON.stringify(eventObjects));
    // node.log(JSON.stringify(server));
    
    var $this = this;

    this.sandboxFlowContext.set("ApiFact", "");

    node.log($this.sandboxFlowContext.get("ApiFact"));
    
    coreServer.internalDebugLog("init dynamic address space");
    const rootFolder = addressSpace.findNode("RootFolder");
    
    node.warn("construct new address space for OPC UA");
    
    const myDevice = namespace.addFolder(rootFolder.objects, {
    "browseName": "FotovoltaicasDallas"
    });

    const apiFact = namespace.addVariable({
    "organizedBy": myDevice,
    "browseName": "ApiFact",
    "nodeId": "ns=1;s=ApiFact",
    "dataType": "String",
    "value": {
      "get": function() {
        return new Variant({
          "dataType": DataType.String,
          "value": $this.sandboxFlowContext.get("ApiFact")
        });
      }
      /*,
      "set": function(variant) {
        flexServerInternals.sandboxFlowContext.set(
          "apiFact",
          parseFloat(variant.value) // TODO
        );
        return opcua.StatusCodes.Good;
      }
      */
    }
    });
    
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Add a view
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    const viewDI = namespace.addView({
    "organizedBy": rootFolder.views,
    "browseName": "FotovoltaicasDallas-View"
    });
    
    viewDI.addReference({
    "referenceType": "Organizes",
    "nodeId": apiFact.nodeId
    });
    
    coreServer.internalDebugLog("create dynamic address space done");
    node.warn("construction of new address space for OPC UA done");
    
    done();
}
```

#### What did you expect to happen?

It should update the OPC UA node.